# Proving that a sequence of function does not uniformly converge

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function

I am trying to prove that the sequence of functions $f_n (t) = n^2 t e^{-nt}$ does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. I was able to show that it converges point-wise to the zero function. To prove that it doesn't converge uniformly, I need to show that
$$
\exists x, \exists \epsilon, \forall N, \exists n > N, |f_n (t)| \geq \epsilon. 
$$
I found that $f_n (t)$ has a maximum of $\frac{n}{e}$ at $t = \frac{1}{n}$, but I'm stumped because I can't choose an $x$ that depends on $n$. Is it preferable to proceed by contradiction?

Comment: $\sup_t f_n(t)\ge f_n(\frac  1n)=e^{-1}$.

Comment: @geetha290krm That makes sense, but I'm not sure how to reconcile the use of the supremum with the definition I wrote down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your negation is not correct as written, it seems to me. Uniform convergence, once we know that the limit is $0$, is $\def\e{\varepsilon}$

> $$\tag1
> \forall \e>0,\ \exists n_0,\ \forall n\geq n_0,\ \forall x,\ |f_n(x)|<\e.
> $$

Hence the negation is

> $$\tag2
> \exists \e>0,\ \forall n_0,\ \exists n\geq n_0,\ \exists x,\ |f_n(x)|\geq\e.
> $$

So we need to find an $\e>0$ and, given an arbitrarily large $n$, an $x_n$ such that $|f_n(x_n)|\geq\e$. Since the function is uniformly continuous away from $0$ (being bounded, continuous, with limit zero at infinity) the problem has to occur at $0$. If we take $x_n=\frac1n$, then
$$
f_n(x_n)=n^2\frac1n\,e^{-n\,\frac1n}=ne^{-1}.
$$
So if we take $\e=e^{-1}$, given any $n_0\in\mathbb N$ we can take $n=n_0+1$, and $x_n=\frac1n$, to get $f_n(x_n)\geq e^{-1}$.